# ServletContext or Properties class

Tags: java, servlets

I'm developing a Servlet that has different operations that depend on different parameters, say default values. However, I want to be able to change these values at run-time, through a jsp or command-line interface. Also, there are many different classes (mostly commands for each operation) that need to be able to access these parameters. Should I be storing these values in a bean MyProperties class that wraps java's Properties class to load up the values from a file and then change them? Or should I load them into the servlet's application context and get/set them from there?

Comment: Do you have to change those values **during** runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do both. Create and put the `MyProperties` class in the servlet context once on application's startup in `ServletContextListener#contextInitialized()`. Then you can get the stored instance from the servlet context in every servlet and JSP the usual way and retrieve/manipulate the properties through the `MyProperties` class accordingly.

This way you end up with only one attribute in the servlet context instead of countless attributes for each single property. This way you also don't need to fiddle with statics and singletons inside `MyProperties` which would not be abstractable or testable.

Comment: What do you mean by statics and singletons?

Comment: Ah you're already not using them :) Don't worry then, just put `MyProperties` in servlet context.

Answer (score 2):

Store those config properties in DB. Always go to the DB and get the latest config. If performance is the issue then I suggest to cache them on the DB side to keep it simple.

If you need ultimate performance then I suggest you lLoad them during application startup (may be Servlet.init() or ServletContextListener). But this needs more code to make sure the updates to the db and cache are kept in sync.

Comment: I should store them in the ServletContext?

Answer (score 1):

You could keep these default `values of properties` as `public static` fields of a `public class`, say a properties class. You can share them among different parts of the application since you will be able to get and set them easily.